# define order of validations in ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

in ef with data annotation, gives there a way to defined the order of validations? or has data annotation a fixed order (by name)?

here what i mean

```
public class ClassX {

    [ValidationB]
    public int Value1 {get;set;}

    [ValidationA]
    [ValidationB]
    public int Value2 {get;set;}
}
```

at first, it should execute ValidationB for all fields then ValidationA

i know, with Fluent API is it possible, but that's not the way i'd like to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the few methods available since EF 4.1 like

- Implementing IValidatableObject
- DbContext.ValidateEntity

These will validate your entities when calling SaveChanges, they let you write custom validation logic thus allowing to specify any order you want.

Also you can Explicitly Trigger Validation and handle each of the errors

[Entity Framework Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193959(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: This will probably be the solution. Thanks